# why gradient descent does not always land at the global minimum closest to the starting point?

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, gradient-descent, non-convex-optimization, global-optimization

I am given this function $\boxed{f(x,y)=((x^2+y^2)-1)^2}$. I need to do gradient descent analysis on it.

I have studied that it's not trivial to show mathematically  **"ball reaches to the global minima closest to the starting point"**.

I want to explore this over my function..

I have  computed,
$$\nabla f=\left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial x},\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)$$
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = 4x\left(x^2+y^2-1\right)
$$
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = 4y\left(x^2+y^2-1\right)
$$

Next What should I do. Can anyone make me understand why gradient descent does not always land at the global minimum closest to the starting point in this function's context ?

Comment: Can you clarify the question? It is currently unclear what you are asking

Comment: I want to do entire gradient analysis of this function mathematically and I want to see why is it not easy to prove the quoted statement arbitarily for any function

Comment: Not sure I understand you correctly. Assuming you want an explanation to "why gradient descent does not always land at the global minimum closest to the starting point". Say you start at $(2,0)$, the negative gradient points to $(-1,0)$, and you take a step of length 3 and reaches $(-1,0)$, which has zero gradient and you won't step any further from this point. But the nearest minimum to $(2,0)$ resides at $(1,0)$. It could be worse, if you take a step of length 2, you go to a local maximal at $(0,0)$ and stops there.

Comment: Contexts are missing in this question, e.g., the starting point, the optimization algorithm, the step size, etc.

Comment: @trisct, I have edited the question. I want to understand this question mathematically using this function

Comment: Does the counterexample in my comment above answer the question?

Comment: Those points ,what have u taken arbitary right? Can you answer in the context of this function? I have searched over web, I haven't find any mathematical step by step explanation of gradient analysis of a function, I want to understand it very deeply

Comment: It depends on how you do your step size. Unless you elaborate the result is not necessarily true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, gradient descent is not guaranteed to reach even the closest  local minimum. This is because the function may have saddle points to get stuck in or run off to infinity (there is a local minimum, but no global minimum). If you want to understand these "failure" cases, I'd suggest you pick one of those functions. It is generally not well understood why, in practice, gradient descent often performs well even on non-convex functions.

If you want to understand the theory behind the guarantees that **do** exist, you should look into convex, strongly convex and smooth (Lipschitz-continuous gradients) functions.

For non-convex functions such as yours there is *trajectory analysis*, which - depending on the initial point and step size - can show that a function has certain "nice" properties along the trajectory of gradient descent. Using these properties one is sometimes able to show convergence to local or global minima, even convergence rate guarantees.

In the case of your function, however, one can use some basic trajectory analysis to show that, using a suitable stepsize, **we will** reach the closest global minimum, if the initial point $x_0 \neq \bf{0}$. The key here is to exploit the fact that $f$ behaves like $(z^2-1)^2$ along any direction $z \in \mathbb{R}^2$. It is easy to see that there exists some direction $z$ with $x_0=\lambda z, \, \lambda > 0$ and any (small enough) step along the gradient will again yield an iterate $x_t\in\{\lambda z \,|\,\lambda > 0 \}$. This is all for the trajectory analysis part and it shows we can reduce to the case of $f(x)=(x^2-1)^2,\, x>0$. $f$ is convex on $[\frac 1 2,\infty)$ so for the iterates from the left you also need to show that for any strictly positive step size you get into this range eventually and you can reduce to this easier case: You should be able to show that for some $\mu > 0, L > 0$, the function is $\mu$-strongly convex and $L$-smooth on $[\frac 1 2,x_0]$. It is then well known that gradient descent with stepsize $\gamma=\frac 1 L$ will converge to the global minimum.

Note that we cheated a bit here since you generally cannot choose $L$ quite like this without knowing the function analytically. This weakens our statement a bit. There is probably also a much simpler way that does not involve all this existing theory, but it is probably necessary to know it anyway, given that OP asked for a very deep understanding.

Comment: Thanks! I am new to this field. I don't know about Trajectory Analysis. I have got some insight from your answer. Can you elaborate the process a bit! So here partials are of no use?

Comment: I don't know how much time you have, but you can look into "Convex Optimization – Boyd and Vandenberghe" to cover classical optimization topics. Trajectory Analysis isn't a well established term as it seems and influential results using the technique have (only?) recently popped up in [A Convergence Analysis of Gradient Descent for Deep Linear Neural Networks](https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.02281). By itself, it is nothing fancy, really. The partials are not useless, but also not necessary, because we have reduced the problem to the 1-dimensional case.